# Get JavaScript working in a reloaded AJAX box

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

When I use AJAX for part of my page, such as a commentbox, in the reloaded box no JavaScript works. e.g. like [`cutetime`](http://tpgblog.com/cutetime/) or whatever. So I guess I have to reload the `cutetime` command (in every reload of the commentbox)

It works, but I think I have the `cutetime` command twice. If I have a confirm box or anything other, I get the confirm box or the add command twice.

I'll try to describe it in one sentence:
**I need a way to get JavaScript working in a reloaded AJAX-Box.**

P.S.: I think there is a very easy way because everybody uses it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace an element anything attached to it is lost.

When using jQuery, you can avoid this issue by using live events. However, this doesn't work for plugins where you don't attach events. In that case you need to call whatever function enables something on your element again when replacing it.

Comment: How can I call whatever function enables something on my element again when replacing it in cgridview. If I post a question could you answer this?