# Javascript function not working after ajax request in CListView

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, jquery-events

I am using CListView widget (yii framework) like this:

```
<?
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
    )); 
    ?>
```

I have few button in "_view" and a process.js file where I have attached click event with buttons like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a#beerButton").click(function(){
            alert('clicked');
        });
    
   });
```

They are working fine in initial page display but after ajax update (Clistview pagination to view next page), no button is responding. What is causing the problem. Shall I have to include the js files again on update.

**EDIT:**

---

`on()` event solved the problem :) Its working now.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892244/get-javascript-woking-in-a-reloaded-ajax-box)

Comment: where is your process.js? i mean how did you include it in the view and in which file?

Comment: I have included the process.js in the main file (common  file in yii applications).

Comment: This solved the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892244/get-javascript-woking-in-a-reloaded-ajax-box

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a#beerButton").live('click', function(){
            alert('clicked');
        });

   });
```

Comment: I have already mentioned it in comments. Anyway delegate() is preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

check your js code some")" and "}" are missing use fire bug to avoid these sort of probs...

Comment: I have confirmed for syntax error in Chrome (Developer Tools). It is correct. Further it is working fine initially.